# Local Meteor Package not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mocha.js

I'm having trouble setting up my project to use a local meteor package instead of a "remote" one. The meteor package I'm trying to use locally is a copy of [meteortesting:mocha](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-mocha) (so I can put my own logs into it).

Here's what I've done:

- Git cloned the meteortesting:mocha repo onto my machine
- Copied the repo into my project root folder with `cp -r [PATH]/meteor-mocha **.**`
- Set `METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS=./meteor-mocha`

But when I run `meteor add meteortesting:mocha` (which is the name of my local package in ./meteor-mocha/package/package.js) it still adds the registered/online meteortesting:mocha package instead of finding my local one.

I also tried fooling around with the name of my local package (i.e. name:"meteortesting:mochalocal") to differentiate it, but when I ran meteor add meteortesting:mochalocal it gives the error "error: no such package"

Does anyone know why this may be the case? I based my set up on [this article](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages)

I know I can also try to put it in ./packages, but I wasn't sure how to approach that with [this repo](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-mocha) because it's more than just a package.js folder.

UPDATE 9/12:
Here is what I've tried (which doesn't work) with adding my local package to ./packages:
[image: Added Local Package In ./packages]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `./packages` folder inside your project. Copy the package folder inside this. Then you will have:

`./packages/meteortesting:mocha`

Or you can use another folder to your packages. Example:

`/home/my_packages`

Then set this:

`METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS=/home/my_packages`

Then your package will be in this path:

`/home/my_packages/meteortesting:mocha`

Comment: Hi Ricardo - thanks for the feedback.

However, when I add the package to ./packages, I am still experiencing an error that my local package can't be found. I think this may be because there is an intermediate folder ("package") within meteor-mocha that makes the filepath to package.js of my local package ./packages/meteor-mocha/package/package.js. I will update my original post with a screenshot of this

Comment: Try to move the content of `meteor-mocha/package` to `meteor-mocha`. I don't believe the other files are necessary.